# Access attribute name with on "click" event handler

Tags: elm

I am trying to access an elements HTML properties when clicked. I figured out that `Events.onClick` will only return `event.target.value` and I need to use `Events.on` to handle custom behaviours.

What I need is: when click on a `div` I should be able to access its HTML properties, for now `id` and `name` and send this value to update with some message.

I tried like this:

```
onClickData : msg -> Attribute msg
onClickData handler =
    on "click" (Decode.succeed handler )
---
view: ...
    ....
    div[onClickData HandleClick] []
```

This way i am able to trigger `HandleClick` action when the `div` is clicked but cannot access its HTML properties.

Comment: Why would you do that? There are no attributes on the element you're attaching the event handler to, and if there were you'd already have access to the value. Why go the long way through an HTML attribute and decoder to retrieve what you already have? Perhaps you should try describing your problem at a higher level, as this seems very much like [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @glennsl has noted, you normally would want to do something more like this:

```
view identification =
    button [ id identification, onClick (MyMsg identification) ] 
        [ text "Click me" 
        ]
```

i.e. you can pass data straight into your `Msg` type.

---

That said, there are some unusual inter-op situations where you might want to do this. The general principle is that you can get the element that you bound your event handler to from `event.currentTarget`, so you can use the following decoder:

```
decodeProperty : String -> Decoder a -> Decoder a 
decodeProperty property decoder = 
   Decode.at ["currentTarget", property] decoder


--- use

onClickId : (String -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onClickId tagger =
    on "click" (Decode.map tagger (decodeProperty "id"))
```

Comment: @glennsl, 
thanks for the quick response, 
i know the example i mentioned above is not a real usecase or what i want to use on app but i was just curious on how to access `event` and attributes in it like we do in other js frameworks example: in react `onClick={(event) => ...}` .
so just used this rough example !

But thanks for stating it out and teaching me a new thing (the XY problem)
:)